# Returning the topmost directory owned by a user if nothing is owned by another user in that directory

Tags: linux, find

Take the following directory structure and ownership:

```
userA ./dir1          
userA ./dir1/dir1.1
userA ./dir1/dir1.2
userA ./dir2
userA ./dir2/dir2.1
userA ./dir2/dir2.1/dir2.1.1
userB ./dir2/dir2.2
userB ./dir3
```

Running `find . -type d -user userA` will return:

```
./dir1          
./dir1/dir1.1
./dir1/dir1.2
./dir2
./dir2/dir2.1
./dir2/dir2.1/dir2.1.1
```

But I am looking to see this output:

```
./dir1
./dir2/dir2.1
```

- `dir1.1` and `dir1.2` are not returned because no other user owns any files/dirs under `dir1`.
- Similarly, `dir2.1.1` is not returned.
- `dir2` is not returned (although it's owned by userA) because `dir2.2` is owned by userB.

This can be useful for disk cleanup so the user can identify which directories are "safe" to run `rm -rf` on. When there are billions of files `du` has a very high runtime. Also limiting the depth of the search doesn't help because the directories could be at any hierarchy level.

Comment: Please give more detailed example of directories ownership.

Comment: If dir1's subdirectories are owned by another user, they won't show up in the output. So what's the problem?

Comment: Is this "I want to identify the outermost directories whose transitive contents are all owned by user X"? I don't think `find` is able to do that, nor any possible post-processing of the output. You'd need to build some sort of custom filter, I think.

Comment: We cannot see; you haven't shown the ownership of the various directories. Please show us.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for your feedbacks. I have modified the question and hope it is more clear now. Sorry about being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -

u="$1"
shift

find "$@" -type d -user "$u" ! -exec sh -c '
   find "$2" -type d ! -user "$1" | grep -qm 1 .
' find-sh "$u" {} \; -prune -print
```

Example usage:

```
/path/to/the_script userA ./
```

The first argument (here `userA`) is the user name. Everything that follows (here `./`) will be passed to `find`; you should pass starting path(s) this way (although injecting tests is technically possible).

The script uses main `find` to find directories owned by the user. For such directory another `find` is invoked, it finds subdirectories not owned by the user. If there is none, the directory is pruned (so the main `find` will not check its subdirectories) and its pathname is printed.

Notes:

- If the inner `find` finds anything then the outer (main) `find` will not prune the directory, it will check its subdirectories. If what the inner `find` found is deep down then many subdirectories on different levels will be checked many times "in vain" before the script moves on to another branch of the directory tree. Unless the directory tree is very big, the OS should cache the metadata and the next `find` checking the same subdirectory should be fast. Checking multiple times seems suboptimal, but any attempt to optimize this would complicate the code; IMO it's not worth it.
- `grep -m 1` exits after the first match, but this option is not portable. If your `grep` does not support `-m` then simply don't use it (i.e. use `grep -q .`). The script will be slower but it will work.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- The title says "if nothing is owned by another user" but your example and the use case suggests "if no subdirectory is owned by another user". My script checks (sub)directories only. To check "if nothing …" omit the `-type d` test in the invocation of the inner `find`.
- `Permission denied` errors may result in false positives.